# Updating Inventory on Clover Pos using the rest api

Tags: php, api, clover-payment

I'm trying to use clover's API to update inventory using a custom built inventory app for my families small business. I have used their APIs without issue for other functions. However, I cannot get it to update the stock of my items.

I followed their documentation here:
https://www.clover.com/api_docs/#!/inventory/UpdateItemStock

However, I cannot seem to figure out where to put the new inventory count so that it will update clovers systems.

I know this is the base URL to access the API `https://api.clover.com/v3/merchants/{{mId}}/item_stocks/{{itemID}}`

(I'm currently using postman for testing so it will fill in the variables in the URL, and insert my API key in an authorization header)

I have tried:

- Appending `quantity=5.0` to the URL for example:
  `https://api.clover.com/v3/merchants/{{mId}}/item_stocks/{{itemID}}?quantity=5.0`
- Sending `quantity=5` as part of the body

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: H do you get any error messages back from your requests? (I'm no expert, but any information you have will help people solve your problem)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are sending a POST to the endpoint:

`POST /v3/merchants/{mId}/item_stocks/{itemId}`

And put this in the body of the request:

```
{
  "quantity": 5
}
```